# Filtering a list with multiple conditions

Tags: java-8, kotlin, higher-order-functions

I have a data structure that resembles this:

```
[{option : {some object A},
  feature : "some string value",
  score : 0.9
 },
{option : {some object B},
  feature : "some other string value",
  score : 0.9
 },
{option : {some object C},
  feature : "some string value",
  score : 0.6
 },{option : {some object D},
  feature : "some string value",
  score : 1.0
 }]
```

I want to filter options with a unique feature. In case where feature is identical, I want to take the one with highest score. For the example above, the expected outcome would be:

```
[{option : {some object B},
  feature : "some other string value",
  score : 0.9
 },{option : {some object D},
  feature : "some string value",
  score : 1.0
 }]
```

Sample implementation (pseudocode) in Kotlin / Java 8 is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Since you didn't provide starting code, I converted your data to Kotlin like this as an example:

```
data class Item(val feature: String, val score: Double)

val options = listOf(
        Item("some string value", 0.9),
        Item("some other string value", 0.9),
        Item("some string value", 0.6),
        Item("some string value", 1.0)
)
```

What you need is essentially just the [`groupBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) function, the rest is pretty simple from there:

```
val highestOfEachFeature = options
        .groupBy { it.feature }
        .map { it.value.maxBy { it.score } }
```

The result is the following:

```
[Option(feature=some string value, score=1.0), Option(feature=some other string value, score=0.9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to zsmb13's correct answer, I would like to propose a more concise syntax using [property references](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#property-references) and [destructuring declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html):

```
val highestOfEachFeature = options
    .groupBy(Item::feature)
    .map { (_, list) -> list.maxBy(Item::score) }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I may borrow zsmb13's declarations, the same result can be produced by:

```
val highestOfEachFeature = options
        .sortedByDescending { it.score }
        .distinctBy { it.feature }
```

Comment: I tried to think of a case where your code fails... I failed! +1

Comment: @WilliMentzel It's the way Kotlin implements `distinctBy`. I've tested it too and found that since `distinctBy` keeps the 1st distinct element of each group then this should do .

Comment: exactly my obersavation!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Java 8 if you want to group by one key and apply an aggregation function to a value in the group, even though Kotlin has a much nicer and concise syntax.

Here is a Java 8 example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Item> items = Arrays.asList(new Item("car", 2.1), new Item("car", 1.1),
            new Item("bus", 3.1), new Item("bus", 4.2), new Item("motorbike", 4.6));
    Map<String, Optional<Double>> collect = items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Item::getVal,
            Collectors.mapping(Item::getScore, Collectors.maxBy(Double::compare))));
    System.out.println(collect);
}


static class Item {
    String val;
    double score;

    Item(String val, double score) {
        this.val = val;
        this.score = score;
    }

    String getVal() { return val; }

    double getScore() { return score; }
}
```

If you execute this code you will see on the console:

```
{motorbike=Optional[4.6], bus=Optional[4.2], car=Optional[2.1]}
```